# Create void tag / self-closing tag for custom element

Tags: html, emmet

I want to create a custom void tag:

```
<mycustomtag />
```

Currently, when I type

```
mycustomtag
```

it gets transformed to

```
<mycustomtag></mycustomtag>
```

Is there a way in Emmet to make the tag void? I couldn't find it in the [docs](http://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/).

Comment: IIRC, self-closing tags are *very* special to the HTML parser, and usually can't be done reliably, but I'm interested if there is a proper solution!

Comment: @ScottKaye - You are correct, and there isn't any mechanism in the HTML parser for custom void tags.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using [emmet-vim](https://github.com/mattn/emmet-vim) and they have added support for self-closing tags [recently](https://github.com/mattn/emmet-vim/commit/1fe780000bb76319d40377360d050631cf526076).

The syntax is:

```
customtag/
```

which will expand to

```
<customtag />
```